# Multiplying matrix location by a scalar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have ran into a slight problem with my matlab code as I am trying to multiply individual cell locations by a constant scalar value for displaying purposes.

**A is a 150x150 matrix of random decimal numbers

```
hLocalMax = vision.LocalMaximaFinder;
hLocalMax.MaximumNumLocalMaxima = 22500;
hLocalMax.NeighborhoodSize = [3 3];
hLocalMax.Threshold = 0;
location = step(hLocalMax, A);

new_location = unique(location,'rows');
new_location = new_location.*0.1;

disp(new_location)
```

Now, my answer is rounding to closest int value

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're referencing but I think you're saying new_location is an int and you want it to be a double. This is some sample.

```
A =randn(150);
hLocalMax = vision.LocalMaximaFinder;
hLocalMax.MaximumNumLocalMaxima = 22500;
hLocalMax.NeighborhoodSize = [3 3];
hLocalMax.Threshold = 0;
location = step(hLocalMax, A);

new_location = double(unique(location,'rows'));
new_location = new_location.*0.1;

disp(new_location)
0.1000    0.1000
0.1000    0.2000
0.1000    0.6000
0.1000    0.8000
0.1000    1.0000
0.1000    1.4000
0.1000    1.6000
0.1000    1.8000
0.1000    2.1000
0.1000    2.3000
0.1000    2.6000
0.1000    3.3000
0.1000    3.7000
0.1000    5.3000
0.1000    5.6000
0.1000    5.9000
0.1000    6.2000
0.1000    6.5000
0.1000    7.5000
0.1000    8.2000
```

Comment: it was no problem